# Validating Forms

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form that I submit with jQuery ajax and have it being sent to a controller function called submit to validate and do any other tasks I need to with the form data. I'm trying to find out why my form validation library isn't showing an error when the username doesn't contain only lowercase letters and numbers.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|strtolower');
```

POST Value after form submission:

```
username    TestingUSER
```

EDIT:

As far as I know it gets to the php server side properly.

PHP:

```
public function submit()
{
    $output_status = 'Notice';
    $output_title = 'Not Processed';
    $output_message = 'The request was unprocessed!';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|strtolower');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('remember', 'Remember Me', 'trim|xss_clean|integer');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $output_status = 'Error';
        $output_title = 'Form Not Validated';
        $output_message = validation_errors();
    }

    echo json_encode(array('output_status' => $output_status, 'output_title' => $output_title, 'output_message' => $output_message));
}
```

EDIT 2:

Based off of Sheikh answer. I am getting a response back that says "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name." It does say Form Not Validated for the title so the message isn't working.

```
public function check_username($str)
{
    if (preg_match('#[0-9]#', $str) && preg_match('#[a-z]#', $str)) 
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_message('username', 'This is not have an accepted value!');
    return FALSE;
}
```

EDIT 3:

What I'm wanting to do is have it report back that there there are validation errors but not the specific errors in the pnotify response. However I do want it to display the specific errors under the form elements.

jQuery Code:

http://pastebin.com/1KehMJkh

Login Form:

http://pastebin.com/EfpBfbfN

Comment: Please show your actual ajax/javascript code and your actual controller code. Does it work without ajax?

Comment: @KevinSmith, field name should be `check_username` instead of `username`, i.e. `$this->form_validation->set_message('check_username','...')` when setting it from a `callback` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a callback function in your controller

```
public function check_username($str)
{
    if (preg_match('#[a-z0-9]#', $str)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username', 'This is not have an accepted value!');
    return FALSE;
}
```

Validation rules for `username`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_username');
```

[You may like this too](http://www.witheringtree.com/2011/09/custom-codeigniter-validation-methods/).

Comment: This is a great answer however I'm curious to know about why you have an alpha numeric rule AND the callback both.

Comment: @KevinSmith, Thanks, just added `alpha_numeric` but not necessary.

Comment: Can you check out my Edit 2 response.

Comment: @KevinSmith, it should be `check_username` instead of `username` as field name in your `set_message`.

Comment: @KevinSmith, Sorry! Not familiar with `pnotify` and to print specific error messages you need to send the response in such a way that you can find out which message belongs to which element.